# Best way to store metric data used for graphs

Tags: postgresql, database-design

What is the best way to store metrics data used in displaying graphs?

Currently I have a table `analytics(domain::text, interval_in_days::int, grouping::text, metric::text, type::text, labels[], data[], summary::json)`

`domain` is the overall category of the metrics. Like what part of the application they're under. Could be `sales` or `support` etc.

the `interval_in_days` and `grouping` are 'view options' the end user can specify at the interface level to have a different view of the data points.

`grouping` can be `date`, `day_of_week` or `time_of_day`
`interval_in_days` can be `7, 30 or 90`

`labels` is an array of the labels on the x-axis and `data` are the corresponding datapoints.

`type` is either `data_series` or `summary`. If `data series`, the row represent's the data used for drawing the graph, while a `summary` has the `summary:json` field populated with an object like `{total_number_of_X: 132, median_X: 320.. etc}`

`metric` is simply the metric the corresponding graph represents, so there's a separate graph for each value of `metric`

From this it follows that for each metric/graph I display, I have 9 (3 intervals * 3 groupings). For each `domain` I have a single row with type `summary`.

Every few hours I aggregate a lot of data across multiple tables into the analytics table. So I don't have to perform expensive queries adhoc.

I feel this is not the optimal approach, so I'm really interested in seeing how other people accomplishes the same task or any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with storing 9 rows of raw data and later aggregating them to something more comfortable. It's a common approach and has performance benefits in some situations.

What I would really re-think in your design are the datatypes. From your description it seems you can transform all `::text` fields into something like `::varchar(20)`. Then you can use STORAGE PLAIN on these columns and your table will become more efficient.

Also, consider adding foreign keys to describe what is stored in individual columns. For example, you stated `grouping` can be `date`, `day_of_week` or `time_of_day`, so you could have a `groupings` table that will list these options. But again, the foreign key would have to be covered by an index, so you may want to skip on that due to performance reasons.